# XAMPP cant uploading a image to my localhost database

Tags: php, html, xampp

Problem with uploading a image to my localhost database.
I have just install XAMPP version 3.2.1 for window(32) but iam useing the window 7 (64) can that be the problem?
My Apcahe and MySQL is running.
Iam useing this code and yes my file is in the htdocs folder.
everytime i try to upload an image i get

Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.
If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404

```
<html>

<head>
        <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="image"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>


<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        mysql_select_db("ZeroWebsite");

        $imageName = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
        $imageData = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));

        if(substr($imageType,0,5) == "image")
        {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `myimage` VALUES('','@imageName','$imageData')");
            echo "image Uploaded!";
        }
        else
        {
        echo "working code";
}
}
?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I will advise you to try to put your code in `htdocs/your-app` folder. Because by default `htdocs/index.php` will open xampp first page. Maybe try to change `action="index.php"` into `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"`? Did you name your file with index.php?

Comment: @Permana no i did not name it index.php, i name it uploadimage and it is in htdocs/ZeroWebsite/uploadimage.php. you want me to change it to <form =action="<?php echo $_SERVER['uploadimage.php'] ?>"  ?

Comment: Ahh, I see. In that case, you should change it to `action="uploadimage.php"`

Comment: @Permana thanks but now i get this: Notice: Undefined variable: imageType in C:\xampp\htdocs\ZeroWebsite\uploadimage1.php on line 23
working code and my line 23 is: if(substr($imageType,0,5) == "image")

Comment: Because $imageType is not given a value. Maybe try adding this line below $imageData: `$imageType = $_FILES["image"]["type"];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form is submitting to a URL that doesn't exist, hence the 404 error. Are you sure `index.php` exists and is in the correct location for what's specified in the `action` attribute of the form?

If your project is in a subdirectory of `htdocs` that could be causing your problem.

Also, your PHP code will likely throw errors, but that's for another question.

Comment: my folder is inside : htdocs/ZeroWebsite/uploadimage.php. do i change the index.php to uploadimage.php then in the <form action="" ? like this <form action="uploadimage.php "